# Package download in terminal

Tags: command-line, updates

Does this means I need 403 MB of internet data to proceed this operation?
[image: 1]

Comment: A perfectly normal update if you haven't been updating regularly as you should.

Comment: Yes, this means you does need 403MB of internet data to proceed that operations.

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm

Comment: @guiverc I, too, can see this is for an EOL version of Ubuntu. However, the question is not remotely unique to the anything in that version.

Answer (score 3):

That is the size of the download. As to actual data usage, that may be slightly higher, as with any download.